# How can I find rows which have a foreign key row with column equal to something

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select all rows from the 'trade' table that have a 'ticker_id' field equal to the 'id' field of a row from the 'ticker' table, that has a 'name' field equal to 'MSFT'?

The 'trade.ticker_id' field is a foreign key to the 'ticker.id' field.
Is this a bad design if I want filter a lot of 'trade' rows?

```
mysql> describe ticker;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| long_name   | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| exchange_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> describe trade;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| time      | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price     | float       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| quantity  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| source    | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| buyer     | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| seller    | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| initiator | varchar(64) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ticker_id | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: show us some of your attempts.

Comment: This is a trivial `JOIN`.

Comment: This is perfect design. Your tables are properly normalized.

Comment: Any decent SQL tutorial should show how to do this. It doesn't matter whether the column is a foreign key or not, the `JOIN` syntax is the same.

Comment: select * from trade inner join ticker on trade.ticker_id = ticker.id where ticker.name = 'MSFT'; I thought there was another way when the other table is a foreign key, that joins were slower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM trade TR 
LEFT JOIN ticker TI ON TR.ticker_id = TI.id
WHERE TI.name =  "MSFT"
```

Comment: Due to the search condition the result is the same as an Inner Join, so remove the `LEFT`.

Comment: this is the right answer. The JOIN speed isn't affected by a foreign key. A foreign key will slow down INSERT statements but  not much else. JOIN would be much slower if ID were not a KEY field.